# partially initialized module (most likely due to a circular import)

Tags: python, module

I have read many many many posts about this topic but everyone says "rename file".
Ive done it multiple times now + renaming classes + renaming instances with no luck, sadly.

[image: Thats My Folder Structure]

Error:
[image]

When I take out "import start" from file "measureSys.py" the program runs until it has to use measureSys.py (missing Main because of course my main class is missing)

```
Top Section (measureSys.py)

import start
from modules import loggingSys
from modules import alarmSys

# Creation of instance(object) of class LoggingSystem to log measurement activity
logging = loggingSys.LoggingSystem()
# Creating instance(object) of class AlarmSystem to be able to send alarms to user/email
alarm = alarmSys.AlarmSystem()

starting = start.Main()

class MeasureSystem:
```

And the class in "start.py" is named "Main"

```
Top Section (start.py)
from modules import measureSys
    
measureSystem = measureSys.MeasureSystem()
```

If I oversee something, please hit me up :( !

Comment: Do `alarmSys` or `loggingSys` import `measureSys`?

Comment: They do not
logginSys is importing nothing except datetime module ***
alarmSys is importing: loggingSys and some other modules like json, configparser...